# I have created a Gridview from arraylist . I want to colour it vertically but the position gridview counts is horizontally?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm creating an graphical grid view in which I have to color the grid view to show percentage so if I pass 20 it should color first 4 columns.

```
//In Getview method of gridview adapter
 if (position == abcd1[position]) {
    box.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.color.c_blue));
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the orientation in GridView to vertical, or vice-versa.

Comment: I just double checked that, it works with GridLayout not GridView, sorry, but if you run out of options try implementing it GridLayout.

Comment: GridView does not have orientation . I am able to do it by Gridlayout creating views dynamically and adding images dynamically , But will it utilize more memory?

Comment: In your case it will not utilize more memory because the GridLayout is contained within one screen. For instance if you had a GridLayout with items than cant fit on your screen without scrolling than all those items would be populated in memory at the same time. GridView would use an adapter and thus populate only what can fit in the screen conserving memory. In your case it doesn't matter both GridView and GridLayout will use the same amount of memory.